# Defintion of equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm new in electronic and I want to know the exact definition of equivlant circuit. My trouble is that we know for example that a resistance equivalence has same current of the resistances in series for a same tension. If we substitute the resistance in series with the equivalent resistance we obtain another circuit and then we calculate the tension in to the poles of the equivlent resistance. At this point we use this voltage in original circuit, but how we know that in the orginal circuit the tension is the same? I don't see explanation maybe it follows from linearity but textbooks I had read don't say anything about this question.

**Update**

Suppose we have a circuit C and a subcircuit A and let be K the complement circuit of A in C so C=K+A. Now I say that A' is equivalent to A if we consider C'=K+A' calculate the currents and voltages of K in this case and they are the same of K in the original circuit C.
If my definition is correct then we must proof that proposition in all cases we want to show an equivlant circuit such as equivalent resistance.
Correct me if I'm wrong.
I gave that definition because it is what we do in exercises.

**New update**

I have these two circuits:

[image]

I solve the second circuit and I find the voltage on R23, then usually in exercises I use that voltage in first circuit to compute current in R2 and R3 in first circuit. My question is: why the volatage in the second circuit can be used for the first (I want a rigorous proof)? Is there a theorem concerning equivalent circuits (in this case R23 is quivalent of R2, R3 in parallel) embedded in other circuits?

Comment: I think you should replace "tension" by "voltage". I think your native language has the same word (like in Dutch) for tension as for voltage.

Comment: Next, I think you'd better draw a schematic as well because pictures assist understanding text.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say in your update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalence of circuits means that if each was hidden in a black box (no other information from inside) with only their terminals exposed you could not discriminate between them; no matter what you connect to the terminals.

If you provide a certain voltage to the terminals the current through the terminals  will be the same and and vice versa, i.e. if you let flow a certain current through the terminals the voltage across the terminals will be the same for both circuits if they are equivalent.

Note: It does not mean, however, that they would dissipate the same amount of power, i.e. dissipated heat must also be thought to be hidden inside the black box (e.g. a Norton source and a Thevenin source may be equivalent, but in open circuit configuration only the Norton source would create heat; the Thevenin source not).

If it is known that two circuits are **linear** circuits (with 2 terminals) there are some simple criteria to determine whether they are equivalent or not:

- E.g.: If their **open circuit voltage** and their **short circuit current** are both equal then the two linear circuits are equivalent.
- Or more general: 
  if their V-I-characteristics (which are V-I-**lines**) have two points in common then they are equivalent.

Comment: What is the exact mathematical definiton of equivalence circuits?

Comment: See my edit (2nd paragraph)

Comment: Ok, Thank you. My definition is wrong.

Comment: If I have a circuit C with subcircuit A and a circuit C' with subcircuit A', suppose A is equivalent with A'. Is C equivalent with C'?

Comment: No, thats not correct. Just because two circuits C and C' have some equivalent (or even identical) subcircuit in common doesn't make them equivalent. A=A'=a resistor. A TV (=C) contains A and also a radio (=C') contains A' (or even A). Of course a TV is not equivalent to a radio.

Comment: If in a circuit with e.g. 20 resistence I substitute 3 of them with another equivalent can I say the new circuit is equivalent to the first? In exercises we do that.

Comment: If the substitute resistor is equivalent to the 3 resitors it replaces: then yes.

Comment: But where is the proof of the fact that I can replace only some resistance inside a circuit I obtain a new equivalent circuit? Suppose you have three resistence in series r1,r2,32 and I substitute only two r1,r2 and I have a new circuit. By theory I only know that the two resistense are equivalent to the new Req=r1+r3, but who says rigorously that the whole new circuit is equivalent with the first?

Comment: If the new total circuit was not equivalent you would have found a way to discriminate between r1,r2 (original) and its equivalent substitute r_s. Exactly that is, however, not possible, because by definition of equivalence you can not discriminate between r1, r2 and r_s.

Comment: I think that is necessary a theorem that in general prove that if I have A equivalent to A' and B equivalent to B' then A in series with B is equivalent with A' in series with B'. Same theorem for parallel, delta and star configurations.

Comment: I have updated the post. I would like if you can give explanation about that quesiton. I know how to solve that kind of exercises but I want understand deeply why using those methods.

Comment: The voltage across R2 || R3 and the voltage across R23 are both the voltages across the terminals of your subcircuit and its equivalent subcircuit. If the voltages were not equal both subcircuits wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: But by the definiton R2 || R3 is quivalent to R3 if we have apply avoltage we have same current but in this case the voltage is determinated solving the circuits in whole.

Comment: You said: "If the voltages were not equal both subcircuits wouldn't be equivalent." But the definition of two equivalent circuits A, B don't say that when we emebedding that circuits in other we have that A and B have same voltage, at least until we prove that.

Comment: Of course it does: see definition in my answer "...you could not discriminate between them; no matter what you connect to the terminals". If the voltages were different then you could discriminate both circuits simply by connecting your external circuit and a voltmeter and comparing those two voltages. Since both circuits are equivalent it is not possible to discriminate between them, especially not by measuring the voltages across A-B. So the voltages must be equal.

Comment: Sorry but I dont' see the exact locial steps that form your definition I can say that the voltage are equals. Is it possible that we must use linearty of circuit of some other theorem?

Comment: Equivalence is when you can not distinguish both circuits by just "looking" at their terminals (not inside). I hope we don't have to discuss that. So what means do you have to "look" at terminals? Of course one is measuring the voltage across the terminals (another one would be measuring the current through the terminals). So if you cannot distinguish both circuits by the voltages across their terminals, obviously the voltages must be equal. Linearity is not required in this path of reasoning. It is true in general, i.e. also for non-linear circuits.

Comment: "Equivalence is when you can not distinguish both circuits by just "looking" at their terminals" what means exactly in mathematical terms? If I plug two equivalent circuit two different voltages they are not equals then doesn't look the same. Th voltage is not decided by me but by the solution of two circuits. I don't see why they must be the same, sorry.

Comment: Pluging two circuits to **different** external circuits doesn't make sense. You'd even get different results if you did that to the same orignal circuit. Of course you have to plug both circuits to the same external circuit and then look if they bahave differntly (i.e. measure voltage and current at the terminals). Is it really that hard to understand?!?.

Comment: If you want to find out if two mechanical machines are equivalent you don't shake one and hit the other one with a hammer and then compare how they behave. What you do is either shake both and compare if the bahave the same; or hit both with a hammer and compare if they behave the same.

Comment: Yes but my question is another, in definition of equivlaent circuits we apply voltage in each circuit or current but in my example the voltage is not decided by me but depending on the circuit solving kirchhoff equations. The circuits are different so teh equations are not all equals.

Comment: The fact is why these equations give me the same voltage on R2, R3 in first circuit and on R23 in second circuit. If one says that it is the same beacuse are eqivalent one must prove that. If I define that two number a,b are equivalent when a isn not b, I can't use a in substituion of b only beacuse in definition I use the term "equivalent".

Comment: If you have a another question then you should ask it in a new SE question instead of discussing on and on

Comment: I made another SE question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/467835/equivalent-circuit-and-substitution